# iOS - Why is the bottom item on my UIAlertView bold?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

Why is the last item on my `UIAlertView` bold?

[image: bold entry]

I notice this happens on all of my Alert Views, regardless of weather or not I have a `cancelButtonTitle` or how many items I have in the alert view.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can make all of the titles even?

```
- (IBAction)showGender:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *genAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select gender."
                                                   message:nil
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"Male", @"Female", @"Transgender", @"Unknown", nil];
genAlert.tag = 4;
[genAlert show];

}
```

Comment: Show your code for creating the alert view.

Comment: as a side-note, you really shouldn't be using a UIAlertView for this.  Action sheets might be more appropriate.

Comment: Hey, I have updated my answer. Apologies it is not what you really wanted but without looping through the subviews of the UIAlertView it appears that you can't change the default styling. W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no cancel button is set, `Apple` will set it to numberOfButtons - 1.

Try setting `cancelButtonIndex` to `-1` and see if that helps.

W

EDIT: Well thats a pain. Since iOS7 I have been having lots of styling issues with the UIAlertView, specifically not being able to style it like previously. To help out I have made available a few files on github. Just drop them into your project and you will have a clone of UIAlertView that you can fully customise.

https://github.com/awgeorge/WGAlertView

W

Comment: I added `genAlert.cancelButtonIndex = -1;` to my code and this didn't work, is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, just tested this myself and it does appear that apple doesn't allow you to change the font of the cancel button without looping through the subview. Apologies. I have however made a UIAlertView clone as I didn't think apples new iOS7 implementation was very flexible. Let me get you the github link if you would like.

Comment: Thanks! That's annoying, for sure.

Comment: Hey I came back to this issue and was checking out your custom AlertView - It doesn't respond to roatation: it is always facing portrait view.

Comment: I will take a look - Chances are I just haven't handled the on rotation event. I recall there being a method on UIView.